# Using paste within mutate function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as below:

```
year <- c(2016,2017,2018)
xxx <- c(1,2,3)
yyy <- c(4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(year,xxx,yyy)
```

I would like to add a new column to this dataframe that has a column name based on one of the original columns, appended with some additional text such as:

```
paste(colnames(df[2]), 'test', sep = '_')
```

I also want to perform an operation of the values of this new column (e.g multiply it by a constant or construct it from original columns)

I tried to do this with mutate

```
df <- mutate(df, paste(colnames(df[2]), 'test', sep = '_') = df[2]*100)
```

But I receive the following:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "df <- mutate(df, paste(colnames(df[2]), 'test', sep = '_') ="
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:=` if we want to do the evaluation on the lhs

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(!! paste(names(df)[2], "test", sep = "_") := df[[2]] * 100)
```

-output

```
  year xxx yyy xxx_test
1 2016   1   4      100
2 2017   2   5      200
3 2018   3   6      300
```

or use `across`, to loop over the column and create new column by modifying the `.names`

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(2, ~  .x * 100, .names = "{.col}_test"))
```

-output

```
df
  year xxx yyy xxx_test
1 2016   1   4      100
2 2017   2   5      200
3 2018   3   6      300
```